# List Of String Search In Database Using Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a list of string `[Bhavik, Prajapati]`. I need to search this list in a database using a query.

In this table, I have two records and I want only the customer tag column response. I have used this query for that but getting error.

```
select customer_tag from customer_tag where customer_tag in ("Bhavik","Prajapati");
```

I want a list of the tags.

[image]

Comment: Use single quotes for string literals.

Comment: BTW, what error do you get?

Comment: @jarlh thanks, I use single quotes but getting an empty response.

Comment: Storing comma separated values is a mess. It will cause you lots of trouble...

Answer (score 0):

Heyo, if i understand you correctly, you wont get any far with this query, mysql handles it just right.

Youre searching for (String "Bhavik" OR String "Prajapati") == customer_tag.

Change the Where-Clause to

```
WHERE customer_tag LIKE '%Prajapati%' OR customer_tag LIKE '%Bhavik%';
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exactly what is in the `customer_tag` column.  If these are different tags, then they should be in a different table.  If it is more like a customer name, then there is a single value.

If you want a tag that matches *either*, you can use regular expressions:

```
where customer_tag regexp 'Bhavik|Prajapati'
```

If you want *both*, then two regular expressions or `like` will do:

```
where customer_tag like '%Bhavik%' and customer_tag like '%Prajapati%'
```